# How to check when two manifolds $X_a$ and $Y$ intersect transversally

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The question is to find the values of $a$ for which $X_a = \{(x,y,z)\in R^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2 = a\}$ and $Y=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3 | x+y^2+2z = 1\}$ intersect transversally in $R^3$.

If $Y$ had $x^2$ instead of $x$, this would have been much easier. To find $X_a \cap Y$, other than  getting $x^2+z^2-x-2z = a-1$, I am not sure how to simply further to get a condition on $a$. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Following the hints, $T(X_a) = \{(u,v,w)| xu+yv+zw=0\}$ and $T(Y) = \{(u,v,w)|xu+2yv+2zw=0\}$. These two tangent spaces are the same when $x=0$ which means $y^2+z^2 = a$ and $y^2+2z=1$. Thus $(z-1)^2=a$ which means $a\geq 0$ which means $X_a$ and $Y$ intersect nontransversally when $a\geq 0$ and intersect transversally when $a<0$. Does this look right?

Comment: Hint:  Instead of trying to find the intersection points, first figure out where the normal vectors to $X_a$ and $Y$ are parallel.

Comment: I think you can compute the smallest value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ for $(x,y,z)$ on $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From calculus 3, the gradient of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ evaluated at any $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $f(x,y,z)=a$ is a vector that is perpendicular to the surface $f(x,y,z)=a$. Similarly for $g(x,y,z)=x+y^2+2z$, its gradient, and the surface $g=1$.

Note that $X_a$ and $Y$ are surfaces and, generically, they will be transverse. So it will be easier to find where they are *not* transverse. If this happens, the tangent space of their intersection will fail to span 3-space. So, their tangent spaces will be the same. this happens whenever the normals are parallel, hence Jason's comment.

This is a long-winded way of saying use the method of lagrange multipliers:
$$\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$$
And, as usual in this situation, careful with your case analysis!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation!